# Can I use android studio in place of Pycharm for learning Django .. If No.. why? and if Yes ..how?

Tags: python, django, android-studio, pycharm

I am learning Django and the tutorial requires downloading Pycharm, which looks almost similar to my android studio IDE. So, can I do the same with android studio or I will have to download Pycharm ?

Comment: You don't need PyCharm to build Django apps. It's a very good IDE to develop Django/python apps, but VS Code and Atom are alternatives. Even vi and emacs. Just use your favourite IDE. If you're used to Android Studio, you'll like PyCharm since both are built on top of IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to download it. All the programs of Jetbrains are apparently identical. In the background, each program contains rules for the programming language. The rules of java do not follow python. So you should download the language-specific IDE you use.

Comment: To be a bit more precise: Android Studio is built using the IntelliJ Platform, which is an open-source platform for building IDEs. Google used it for Android Studio. Jetbrains, the creator of IntelliJ also uses it for all its IDEs including PyCharm.

Comment: @yusuf  Is there any online tools or editor, which may work rather than downloading the PyCharm

Comment: Unfortunately i have not seen an online alternative for PyCharm.